# Splitting SQL query with many joins into smaller ones helps?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, query-optimization

We need to do some reporting every night on our SQL server 2008R2. Calculating the reports takes several hours. In order to shorten the time we precalculate a table. This table is created based on JOINining 12 quite big (tens of milions row) tables.

The calculation of this aggregation table took until few days ago cca 4 hours. Our DBA than split this big join into 3 smaller joins (each joining 4 tables). The temporar result is everytime saved into a temporary table, which is used in the next join.

The result of the DBA enhancment is, that the aggregation table is calculated in 15 minutes. I wondered how is that possible. DBA told me that it is because the number of data the server must process is smaller. In other words, that in the big original join the server has to work with more data than in summed smaller joins. However, I would presume that optimizer would take care of doing it effeciently with the original big join, splitting the joins on its own and sending only the number of columns needed to next joins.

The other thing he has done is that he created an index on one of the tmeporary tables. However, once again I would think that the optimizer will create the appropriate hash tables if needed and alltogether better optimize the computation.

I talked about this with our DBA, but he was himself uncertain about what cased the improvement in processing time. He just mentioned, that he would not blame the server as it can be overwhelming to compute such big data and that it is possible that the optimizer has hard time to predict the best execution plan ... . This I understand, but I would like to have more defining answer as to exactly why.

So, the questions are:

**1. "What could possibly cause the big improvement?"**

**2. "Is it a standard procedure to split big joins into smaller?"**

**3. "Is the amount of data which srever has to process really smaller in case of multiple smaller joins?"**

Here is the original query:

```
    Insert Into FinalResult_Base
SELECT       
    TC.TestCampaignContainerId,
    TC.CategoryId As TestCampaignCategoryId,
    TC.Grade,
    TC.TestCampaignId,    
    T.TestSetId
    ,TL.TestId
    ,TSK.CategoryId
    ,TT.[TestletId]
    ,TL.SectionNo
    ,TL.Difficulty
    ,TestletName = Char(65+TL.SectionNo) + CONVERT(varchar(4),6 - TL.Difficulty) 
    ,TQ.[QuestionId]
    ,TS.StudentId
    ,TS.ClassId
    ,RA.SubjectId
    ,TQ.[QuestionPoints] 
    ,GoodAnswer  = Case When TQ.[QuestionPoints] Is null Then 0
                      When TQ.[QuestionPoints] > 0 Then 1 
                      Else 0 End
    ,WrongAnswer = Case When TQ.[QuestionPoints] = 0 Then 1 
                      When TQ.[QuestionPoints] Is null Then 1
                     Else 0 End
    ,NoAnswer    = Case When TQ.[QuestionPoints] Is null Then 1 Else 0 End
    ,TS.Redizo
    ,TT.ViewCount
    ,TT.SpentTime
    ,TQ.[Position]  
    ,RA.SpecialNeeds        
    ,[Version] = 1 
    ,TestAdaptationId = TA.Id
    ,TaskId = TSK.TaskId
    ,TaskPosition = TT.Position
    ,QuestionRate = Q.Rate
    ,TestQuestionId = TQ.Guid
    ,AnswerType = TT.TestletAnswerTypeId
FROM 
    [TestQuestion] TQ WITH (NOLOCK)
    Join [TestTask] TT WITH (NOLOCK)            On TT.Guid = TQ.TestTaskId
    Join [Question] Q WITH (NOLOCK)         On TQ.QuestionId =  Q.QuestionId
    Join [Testlet] TL WITH (NOLOCK)         On TT.TestletId  = TL.Guid 
    Join [Test]     T WITH (NOLOCK)         On TL.TestId     =  T.Guid
    Join [TestSet] TS WITH (NOLOCK)         On T.TestSetId   = TS.Guid 
    Join [RoleAssignment] RA WITH (NOLOCK)  On TS.StudentId  = RA.PersonId And RA.RoleId = 1
    Join [Task] TSK WITH (NOLOCK)       On TSK.TaskId = TT.TaskId
    Join [Category] C WITH (NOLOCK)     On C.CategoryId = TSK.CategoryId
    Join [TimeWindow] TW WITH (NOLOCK)      On TW.Id = TS.TimeWindowId 
    Join [TestAdaptation] TA WITH (NOLOCK)  On TA.Id = TW.TestAdaptationId
    Join [TestCampaign] TC WITH (NOLOCK)        On TC.TestCampaignId = TA.TestCampaignId 
WHERE
    T.TestTypeId = 1    -- eliminuji ankety 
    And t.ProcessedOn is not null -- ne vsechny, jen dokoncene
    And TL.ShownOn is not null
    And TS.Redizo not in (999999999, 111111119)
END;
```

The new splitted joins after DBA great work:

```
    SELECT       
    TC.TestCampaignContainerId,
    TC.CategoryId As TestCampaignCategoryId,
    TC.Grade,
    TC.TestCampaignId,    
    T.TestSetId
    ,TL.TestId
    ,TL.SectionNo
    ,TL.Difficulty
    ,TestletName = Char(65+TL.SectionNo) + CONVERT(varchar(4),6 - TL.Difficulty) -- prevod na A5, B4, B5 ...
    ,TS.StudentId
    ,TS.ClassId
    ,TS.Redizo
    ,[Version] = 1 -- ? 
    ,TestAdaptationId = TA.Id
    ,TL.Guid AS TLGuid
    ,TS.TimeWindowId
INTO
    [#FinalResult_Base_1]
FROM 
    [TestSet] [TS] WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN [Test] [T] WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON [T].[TestSetId] = [TS].[Guid] AND [TS].[Redizo] NOT IN (999999999, 111111119) AND [T].[TestTypeId] = 1 AND [T].[ProcessedOn] IS NOT NULL
    JOIN [Testlet] [TL] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [TL].[TestId] = [T].[Guid] AND [TL].[ShownOn] IS NOT NULL
    JOIN [TimeWindow] [TW] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [TW].[Id] = [TS].[TimeWindowId] AND [TW].[IsActive] = 1
    JOIN [TestAdaptation] [TA] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [TA].[Id] = [TW].[TestAdaptationId] AND [TA].[IsActive] = 1
    JOIN [TestCampaign] [TC] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [TC].[TestCampaignId] = [TA].[TestCampaignId] AND [TC].[IsActive] = 1
    JOIN [TestCampaignContainer] [TCC] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [TCC].[TestCampaignContainerId] = [TC].[TestCampaignContainerId] AND [TCC].[IsActive] = 1
    ;

 SELECT       
    FR1.TestCampaignContainerId,
    FR1.TestCampaignCategoryId,
    FR1.Grade,
    FR1.TestCampaignId,    
    FR1.TestSetId
    ,FR1.TestId
    ,TSK.CategoryId AS [TaskCategoryId]
    ,TT.[TestletId]
    ,FR1.SectionNo
    ,FR1.Difficulty
    ,TestletName = Char(65+FR1.SectionNo) + CONVERT(varchar(4),6 - FR1.Difficulty) -- prevod na A5, B4, B5 ...
    ,FR1.StudentId
    ,FR1.ClassId
    ,FR1.Redizo
    ,TT.ViewCount
    ,TT.SpentTime
    ,[Version] = 1 -- ? 
    ,FR1.TestAdaptationId
    ,TaskId = TSK.TaskId
    ,TaskPosition = TT.Position
    ,AnswerType = TT.TestletAnswerTypeId
    ,TT.Guid AS TTGuid

INTO
    [#FinalResult_Base_2]
FROM 
    #FinalResult_Base_1 FR1
    JOIN [TestTask] [TT] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [TT].[TestletId] = [FR1].[TLGuid] 
    JOIN [Task] [TSK] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [TSK].[TaskId] = [TT].[TaskId] AND [TSK].[IsActive] = 1
    JOIN [Category] [C] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [C].[CategoryId] = [TSK].[CategoryId]AND [C].[IsActive] = 1
    ;    

DROP TABLE [#FinalResult_Base_1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [#IX_FR_Student_Class]
ON [dbo].[#FinalResult_Base_2] ([StudentId],[ClassId])
INCLUDE ([TTGuid])

SELECT       
    FR2.TestCampaignContainerId,
    FR2.TestCampaignCategoryId,
    FR2.Grade,
    FR2.TestCampaignId,    
    FR2.TestSetId
    ,FR2.TestId
    ,FR2.[TaskCategoryId]
    ,FR2.[TestletId]
    ,FR2.SectionNo
    ,FR2.Difficulty
    ,FR2.TestletName
    ,TQ.[QuestionId]
    ,FR2.StudentId
    ,FR2.ClassId
    ,RA.SubjectId
    ,TQ.[QuestionPoints] -- 1+ good, 0 wrong, null no answer
    ,GoodAnswer  = Case When TQ.[QuestionPoints] Is null Then 0
                      When TQ.[QuestionPoints] > 0 Then 1 -- cookie
                      Else 0 End
    ,WrongAnswer = Case When TQ.[QuestionPoints] = 0 Then 1 
                      When TQ.[QuestionPoints] Is null Then 1
                     Else 0 End
    ,NoAnswer    = Case When TQ.[QuestionPoints] Is null Then 1 Else 0 End
    ,FR2.Redizo
    ,FR2.ViewCount
    ,FR2.SpentTime
    ,TQ.[Position] AS [QuestionPosition]  
    ,RA.SpecialNeeds -- identifikace SVP        
    ,[Version] = 1 -- ? 
    ,FR2.TestAdaptationId
    ,FR2.TaskId
    ,FR2.TaskPosition
    ,QuestionRate = Q.Rate
    ,TestQuestionId = TQ.Guid
    ,FR2.AnswerType
INTO
    [#FinalResult_Base]
FROM 
    [#FinalResult_Base_2] FR2
    JOIN [TestQuestion] [TQ] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [TQ].[TestTaskId] = [FR2].[TTGuid]
    JOIN [Question] [Q] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [Q].[QuestionId] = [TQ].[QuestionId] AND [Q].[IsActive] = 1

    JOIN [RoleAssignment] [RA] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON [RA].[PersonId] = [FR2].[StudentId]
        AND [RA].[ClassId] = [FR2].[ClassId] AND [RA].[IsActive] = 1 AND [RA].[RoleId] = 1

    drop table #FinalResult_Base_2;

    truncate table [dbo].[FinalResult_Base];
    insert into [dbo].[FinalResult_Base] select * from #FinalResult_Base;

    drop table #FinalResult_Base;
```

Comment: Please add the definition of your query.

Comment: @Devart The original query provided. Also the improved one.

Answer (score 2):

For the first, please, rebuilding indexes on your tables by this script (this may take a long time) -

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
      @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @IndexName SYSNAME
    , @Output VARCHAR(200)
    , @ServerVersion VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @ServerVersion = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR
    SELECT
        'ALTER INDEX [' + ix.name + N'] ON [' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.[schema_id]) + '].[' + t.name + '] ' + 
        CASE
            WHEN ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 50 THEN
                CASE WHEN @ServerVersion LIKE 'Enterprise%' OR @ServerVersion LIKE 'Developer%' THEN
                  'REBUILD WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, ONLINE = ON ' + CASE WHEN ix.fill_factor > 0 THEN ', FILLFACTOR = ' + CAST(ix.fill_factor AS VARCHAR(3)) ELSE '' END + ') '
                ELSE
                  'REBUILD WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON' + CASE WHEN ix.fill_factor > 0 THEN ', FILLFACTOR = ' + CAST(ix.fill_factor AS VARCHAR(3)) ELSE '' END + ') '
            END
            ELSE 'REORGANIZE ' 
        END + 
        CASE
            WHEN ps.partition_number > 1 THEN N' PARTITION = ' + CAST(ps.partition_number AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            ELSE N''
        END + ';', ix.name
    FROM sys.indexes ix
    JOIN sys.objects t ON t.[object_id] = ix.[object_id]
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
              [object_id]
            , index_id
            , avg_fragmentation_in_percent
            , partition_number
        FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, N'LIMITED')
        WHERE page_count > 100
            AND avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 10
    ) ps ON t.[object_id] = ps.[object_id] AND ix.index_id = ps.index_id
    WHERE t.[type] = 'U'
        AND t.name IN (
            'TestQuestion', 'TestTask', 'Question', 'Testlet', 
            'Test', 'TestSet', 'RoleAssignment', 'Task', 
            'category', 'TimeWindow', 'TestAdaptation', 'TestCampaign')

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @SQL, @IndexName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT @Output = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), GETDATE(), 114) + ': ' + @IndexName
    RAISERROR(@Output, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @SQL, @IndexName

END 

CLOSE cur 
DEALLOCATE cur
```

And after it try this query -

```
INSERT INTO dbo.FinalResult_Base
SELECT  
      TC.TestCampaignContainerId
    , TestCampaignCategoryId = TC.CategoryID 
    , TC.Grade
    , TC.TestCampaignId
    , T.TestSetId
    , TL.TestId
    , TSK.CategoryID
    , TT.[TestletId]
    , TL.SectionNo
    , TL.Difficulty
    , TestletName = CHAR(65 + TL.SectionNo) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), 6 - TL.Difficulty)
    , TQ.[QuestionId]
    , TS.StudentId
    , TS.ClassId
    , RA.SubjectId
    , TQ.[QuestionPoints]
    , GoodAnswer =
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(TQ.[QuestionPoints], 0) > 0
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END
    , WrongAnswer =
        CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(TQ.[QuestionPoints], 0) = 0 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    , NoAnswer =
        CASE WHEN TQ.[QuestionPoints] IS NULL 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END
    , TS.Redizo
    , TT.ViewCount
    , TT.SpentTime
    , TQ.[Position]
    , RA.SpecialNeeds
    , [Version] = 1
    , TestAdaptationId = TA.id
    , TaskId = TSK.TaskId
    , TaskPosition = TT.Position
    , QuestionRate = Q.Rate
    , TestQuestionId = TQ.guid
    , AnswerType = TT.TestletAnswerTypeId 
FROM dbo.TestQuestion TQ WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN dbo.TestTask TT WITH (NOLOCK) ON TT.[guid] = TQ.TestTaskId 
JOIN dbo.Question Q WITH (NOLOCK) ON TQ.QuestionId = Q.QuestionId 
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Testlet TL WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE TL.ShownOn IS NOT NULL
) TL ON TT.TestletId = TL.[guid] 
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Test T WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE T.TestTypeId = 1 
        AND T.ProcessedOn IS NOT NULL
) T ON TL.TestId = T.[guid] 
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.TestSet TS WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE TS.Redizo NOT IN (999999999, 111111119)
) TS ON T.TestSetId = TS.[guid] 
JOIN dbo.RoleAssignment RA WITH (NOLOCK) ON TS.StudentId = RA.PersonID AND RA.RoleId = 1 
JOIN dbo.Task TSK WITH (NOLOCK) ON TSK.TaskId = TT.TaskId 
JOIN dbo.category C WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.CategoryID = TSK.CategoryID 
JOIN dbo.TimeWindow TW WITH (NOLOCK) ON TW.id = TS.TimeWindowId 
JOIN dbo.TestAdaptation TA WITH (NOLOCK) ON TA.id = TW.TestAdaptationId 
JOIN dbo.TestCampaign TC WITH (NOLOCK) ON TC.TestCampaignId = TA.TestCampaignId
```

And try this query -

```
SELECT  TC.TestCampaignContainerId
        ,TC.CategoryID AS TestCampaignCategoryId
        ,TC.Grade
        ,TC.TestCampaignId
        ,T.TestSetId
        ,TL.TestId
        ,TL.SectionNo
        ,TL.Difficulty
        ,TestletName = CHAR(65 + TL.SectionNo) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), 6 - TL.Difficulty) -- prevod na A5, B4, B5 ...
        ,TS.StudentId
        ,TS.ClassId
        ,TS.Redizo
        ,[Version] = 1 -- ? 
        ,TestAdaptationId = TA.id
        ,TL.guid AS TLGuid
        ,TS.TimeWindowId
INTO [#FinalResult_Base_1] 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.[TestSet] [TS] WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE [TS].[Redizo] NOT IN (999999999, 111111119) 
) TS
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.[Test] [T] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [T].[TestTypeId] = 1 
        AND [T].[ProcessedOn] IS NOT NULL 
) T ON [T].[TestSetId] = [TS].[guid] 
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.[Testlet] [TL] WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE [TL].[ShownOn] IS NOT NULL 
) TL ON [TL].[TestId] = [T].[guid]
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.[TimeWindow] [TW] WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE [TW].[IsActive] = 1 
) TW ON [TW].[id] = [TS].[TimeWindowId] 
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.[TestAdaptation] [TA] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [TA].[IsActive] = 1 
) TA ON [TA].[id] = [TW].[TestAdaptationId] 
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.[TestCampaign] [TC] WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE [TC].[IsActive] = 1 
) TC ON [TC].[TestCampaignId] = [TA].[TestCampaignId]
--possible unused join in this query
--JOIN dbo.[TestCampaignContainer] [TCC] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [TCC].[TestCampaignContainerId] = [TC].[TestCampaignContainerId] AND [TCC].[IsActive] = 1


SELECT  FR1.TestCampaignContainerId
        ,FR1.TestCampaignCategoryId
        ,FR1.Grade
        ,FR1.TestCampaignId
        ,FR1.TestSetId
        ,FR1.TestId
        ,TSK.CategoryID AS [TaskCategoryId]
        ,TT.[TestletId]
        ,FR1.SectionNo
        ,FR1.Difficulty
        ,TestletName = CHAR(65 + FR1.SectionNo) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), 6 - FR1.Difficulty) -- prevod na A5, B4, B5 ...
        ,FR1.StudentId
        ,FR1.ClassId
        ,FR1.Redizo
        ,TT.ViewCount
        ,TT.SpentTime
        ,[Version] = 1 -- ? 
        ,FR1.TestAdaptationId
        ,TaskId = TSK.TaskId
        ,TaskPosition = TT.Position
        ,AnswerType = TT.TestletAnswerTypeId
        ,TT.guid AS TTGuid
INTO [#FinalResult_Base_2] 
FROM #FinalResult_Base_1 FR1 
JOIN [TestTask] [TT] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [TT].[TestletId] = [FR1].[TLGuid] 
JOIN [Task] [TSK] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [TSK].[TaskId] = [TT].[TaskId] 
--possible unused join
--JOIN [category] [C] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [C].[CategoryID] = [TSK].[CategoryID]
WHERE [TSK].[IsActive] = 1 
    --AND [C].[IsActive] = 1

DROP TABLE [#FinalResult_Base_1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [#IX_FR_Student_Class]
ON [dbo].[#FinalResult_Base_2] ([StudentId], [ClassId])
INCLUDE ([TTGuid])

TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[FinalResult_Base];

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FinalResult_Base]
SELECT  FR2.TestCampaignContainerId
        ,FR2.TestCampaignCategoryId
        ,FR2.Grade
        ,FR2.TestCampaignId
        ,FR2.TestSetId
        ,FR2.TestId
        ,FR2.[TaskCategoryId]
        ,FR2.[TestletId]
        ,FR2.SectionNo
        ,FR2.Difficulty
        ,FR2.TestletName
        ,TQ.[QuestionId]
        ,FR2.StudentId
        ,FR2.ClassId
        ,RA.SubjectId
        ,TQ.[QuestionPoints] -- 1+ good, 0 wrong, null no answer
        , GoodAnswer =
                CASE WHEN ISNULL(TQ.[QuestionPoints], 0) > 0
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0
                END
        , WrongAnswer =
            CASE
                WHEN ISNULL(TQ.[QuestionPoints], 0) = 0 
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        , NoAnswer =
            CASE WHEN TQ.[QuestionPoints] IS NULL 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0
            END
        ,FR2.Redizo
        ,FR2.ViewCount
        ,FR2.SpentTime
        ,TQ.[Position] AS [QuestionPosition]
        ,RA.SpecialNeeds -- identifikace SVP        
        ,[Version] = 1 -- ? 
        ,FR2.TestAdaptationId
        ,FR2.TaskId
        ,FR2.TaskPosition
        ,QuestionRate = Q.Rate
        ,TestQuestionId = TQ.guid
        ,FR2.AnswerType
FROM [#FinalResult_Base_2] FR2 
JOIN [TestQuestion] [TQ] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [TQ].[TestTaskId] = [FR2].[TTGuid] 
JOIN [Question] [Q] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Q].[QuestionId] = [TQ].[QuestionId] AND [Q].[IsActive] = 1 
JOIN [RoleAssignment] [RA] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [RA].[PersonID] = [FR2].[StudentId] 
    AND [RA].[ClassId] = [FR2].[ClassId] 
    AND [RA].[IsActive] = 1 
    AND [RA].[RoleId] = 1

DROP TABLE #FinalResult_Base_2;
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the scripts I will look at them with DBA. However, I was more interested in answering the questions "Why helped what my DBA did". COuld you elaboreate more on that? Or could explain what you were trying to do and why it should help?

Comment: How did you find out please about the possible usnused joins? You noticed it on your own or do you have kind of tool for that? In any case, would not be this handled by optimizer?

Comment: Concerning queries. JOIN can be quite costly in case the fields, that are used for connections, contain NULL values and doesn't have an index. Also, if there is a big number of connections in one query, MSSQL is not always capable to generate an optimal query plan. Your DBA has reduced the amount of JOIN operations and made query more simple. I myself had recourse to such tricks. In some cases they were really justified. However, my advice is that you always need to design a schema taking into account future loads. In this case you will have no such problems.

Comment: Concerning unused joins. I always look at the query plan generated by a profiler (personally I prefer the profiler built into [dbForge for MS SQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/sql-query-profiler.html)). If the table, specified in the query, doesn't appear in the query plan, than it is not used. This is the simplest variant basing on which I assumed that in your case that table was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO It should not be the case, I faced similar problem and took the following steps to optimize it.

- Try putting Indexes on the columns which are used in filtering (The
  columns deciding the joins).
- Try to put indexes on Views, It could be done but It needs some
  special requirements.
- Have some jobs for Index Rebuilding.
- Use another mirror instance of DB for reporting leave the live DB
- Don't use functions while joining if you want to transform data do it
  after joining.
- Use Query optimizer to view what part of join is taking most of the
  time/resources.
- Use an Archive table to purge data into it from live DB.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Something to add we were joining over 20 tables and some main transaction tables in that were having over 1mil transaction per day :)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tips.  We have already tried/done all you have written (besides the last point which is not applicable in our case), but you created nice checklist ;)